# Importing a file from a different directory in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, path

Here are my two folder structures:

```
A/B/C/D/E/F.py

A/B/C/G/H/I/test.py
```

My `test.py` wants to import the class of `F.py`. I have set the root directory to `C`. I tried:

```
from C.D.F import FClassname
```

This is not working. The message is

```
ImportError: No module named C.D.F
```

I have ensure that all the directories have `__init__.py` files. I don't want to add any code to `test.py`. I want to add code in the `__init__.py` so that it applies to all the future test files that I'll write.
In the `__init__.py` of the directory H, I have written the follwing code:

```
import os
import sys
root = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../'))
sys.path.append(root)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python

Comment: It's not getting rectified still.

Answer (score 1):

Use this file structure inside `C`.

```
.
|-- D
|   |-- E
|   |   |-- F.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- __pycache__
|   |       |-- F.cpython-34.pyc
|   |       `-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- __pycache__
|       `-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
`-- G
    |-- H
    |   |-- I
    |   |   `-- foo.py
    |   `-- __init__.py
    `-- __init__.py
```

`foo.py` could then be

```
from D.E import F

F.foo()
```

Run it with [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) including the current directory (`.`) which would be `C`.

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python3.4 G/H/I/foo.py
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

- Create `__init__.py` in the folders `C, D, E`

Then in your `test.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/C')

from C.D.E.F import FClassname
```